# In Chrome packaged apps v2 how to check if the window is maximized?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I created a frameless window using the new Google Chrome packaged apps, v2

I created the minimize, maximize, and close buttons and hocked them to the appropriate JavaScript functions and have them working.

I don’t know who to check if the window is already maximized in JavaScript, any ideas?

The following example is showing how to minimize a window, it took me some time to understand it and implement it, and it works.
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/frameless-window/style.css

The maximize button have to restore the window if maximized, and if you double click the window title bar it maximized but I don’t get any events.

Answer (score 5):

This is currently not possible. [Bug 134068](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=134068) is filed for querying the properties of a window, and [bug 134070](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=134070) is filed for getting events when they change.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be possible now that those mentioned bugs were fixed in the last few weeks.